# Indented block is expected in python 3.5.2

Tags: python

This is the code i wrote for practicing Python Programming as an image:

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ds0cW.png)

and the output is as follows:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1urt.png)

please help me guys. 
PS : I am new to python programming and the installed version is 3.5.2

Comment: Why have you linked to images on another site? Post the code *here*, as *text*.

Comment: But before that, please read any introduction to Python; significant indentation is literally the first thing to know about the language.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming

Comment: All experienced programmers, in any language, indent their conditional blocks of code.  That is, the code which is executed when an `if` is true, and after an `else` is executed.  The message says that python expects an indented block, so why not try that and see what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean to have code that looks something like this:

```
x = 2
x = x + 12
if x < 10:
    print (x , ' is smaller than 10.')
else:
    print (x , 'is greater than or larger than 10.')
```

Because here as you can see there are indents, if you don't already know that about python, you should give the basics a read again. Try [here](ftp://91.193.237.1/pub/docs/linux-support/programming/Python/[O%60Reilly]%20-%20Programming%20Python,%204th%20ed.%20-%20[Lutz]/[O%60Reilly]%20-%20Programming%20Python,%204th%20ed.%20-%20[Lutz].pdf).